# ¿ Como guardar el resultado de una consulta sin guardar 2 veces el mismo dato en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estoy usando la libreria SimpleXLSXGen, quiero mostrar mi consulta de MySQl en Excel. Para mostrar los datos se debe pasar un array para generar el excel, pero cuando hago mi consulta se guarda la clave numerica con su valor y ademas una clave tipo string con su valor. Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$bringHisMain = $connect->prepare("SELECT 
serie,buss_name,tec_assigned,tecCC,tel1,date_maintenance,desc_maintenance FROM 
maintenance_records mr WHERE serie = '$serieH';");
if($bringHisMain->execute()){
   $saveHisMain = $bringHisMain->fetchAll();
}else{
   echo '{}';
}
```

Mi excel se genera de esta manera:

```
$xlsx = Shuchkin\SimpleXLSXGen::fromArray($saveHisMain);
$xlsx->downloadAs('books.xlsx');
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en mi array se esta guardando cada dato 2 veces, entonces cuando lo paso al excel, me muestra cada dato 2 veces. Mi excel se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo lo que quiero ver como resultado es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que hago para limpiar mi array, o como evito que se me guarde 2 veces el mismo dato.

Comment: ¿has probado con fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)?

Comment: Excelente Bro, muchas gracias, algo tan simple se puede volver un dolor de cabeza jajaja

Comment: de nada :-)   No estaba seguro de ello porque no conozco eso del SimpleXLSXGen, pero viendo tu array me he imaginado que por ahi iban los tiros... me alegro que te haya servido. Saludos!

Comment: Los datos estaban duplicados porque no indicabas un *fetch style* al llamar a `fetchAll()`, en ese caso PDO toma el *fetch style* por defecto que es `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` el cual *"devuelve un array indexado tanto por nombre de columna, como numéricamente con índice de base 0 tal como fue devuelto en el conjunto de resultados"*. Al indicar un *fetch style* específico, como bien indica @masterguru, el problema queda resuelto. Eso está explicado con claridad en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) (ver el apartado titulado **fetch style**).